# Print the values of the parameters up the stack trace

Tags: c#, reflection, parameters, stack-trace, stack-frame

Printing the stack trace is not so difficult when using `System.Diagnostics`.  I am wondering if it is possible to print the VALUES of the parameters passed to each method up the stack trace, and if not why not.

Here is my preliminary code:

```
public static class CallStackTracker
{
    public static void Print()
    {
        var st = new StackTrace();
        for (int i = 0; i < st.FrameCount; i++)
        {
            var frame = st.GetFrame(i);
            var mb = frame.GetMethod();
            var parameters = mb.GetParameters();
            foreach (var p in parameters)
            {
                // Stuff probably goes here, but is there another way?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It won't work: `MethodInfo.GetParameters` returns the declared parameters, not the argument values...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque:  Ok, so this particular appraoch may not work.  Is there another that will?

Comment: Only a debugger has a shot at the necessary info, available from the .pdb file.  That however goes down fast from there, a program cannot debug itself and the info is only accurate for the Debug build.  Optimizing method calls is a very important jitter optimizer target.  You can't make this work.

Comment: @HansPassant:  What is it I can't make work?  I'm not sure where you got that I was attempting to optimize anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that, at least not with the classes provided by `System.Diagnostics`. The `StackFrame` class doesn't provide a way to access the argument values (`MethodBase.GetParameters` provides information about the declared parameters, e.g. their names and types, but not the values of the actual arguments)

I think it's possible to do it with the CLR debugging APIs, but probably not from C#

Comment: +1 for the CLR debugging API reference.  I don't see why this wouldn't be made easily available.